# Proof of a matrix is positive semi-definite

Tags: matrices, optimization

For $\ i = 0, 1, \cdots m$, 
$f_{i}(x): R^n \rightarrow R$ is defined to be
$$
f_i(x) = x^TQ_ix + 2p_i^Tx + r_i
$$
, where $Q_0 \cdots Q_m$ are real symmetric matrices, $p_0 \cdots p_m \in R^n$, and
$r_0 \cdots r_m \in R$.

Now, for all $x$ in $R^n$, $f_{0}(x) \geq \sum_{i=1}^{m}t_if_i(x)$ holds
($t_1, \cdots, t_m \in R$).

Please show that the following matrix is positive semi-definite.
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
Q_0 & p_0\\
p_0^T & r_0
\end{pmatrix}
-\sum_{i=1}^{m}t_i
\begin{pmatrix}
Q_i & p_i\\
p_i^T & r_i
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: I think the essence of this problem is:$$\begin{pmatrix}x^T & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}Q & p\\p^T & r \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \geq 0 \Leftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}\xi^T & \eta \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}Q & p\\p^T & r \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\xi \\ \eta \end{pmatrix} \geq 0 $$, for all $x, \xi \in R^n, y \in R$. I have difficulty in showing $r=0\Rightarrow p=0$, which is very important part of my solution.

Comment: It follows from my proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED version

You assume that $F(x)=x^TQx+2p^Tx+r\ge 0$ for all $x$ where $Q=Q_0-\sum_1^m t_iQ_i$, 
$p=p_0-\sum_1^m t_ip_i$, $r=r_0-\sum_1^m t_ir_i$. This implies

1. $F(0)=r\ge 0$.
2. $Q$ is positively semi-definite.
3. $p=QQ^+p$, namely $Qx=0$ implies $p^Tx=0$.

Thus $F(x)$ can be rewritten in the following from 
$$
F(x)=(x+Q^+p)^TQ(x+Q^+p)+r-p^TQ^+p
$$
Then $r\ge p^TQ^+p$. Now the property  we want to prove that for for any $x,a$:

$$
F(x,a)=x^TQx+2ap^Tx+a^2r\ge 0
$$
We can rewrite:
$$
F(x,a)=(x+aQ^+p)^TQ(x+aQ^+p)+a^2r-a^2p^TQ^+p\ge a^2r-a^2p^TQ^+p=a^2(r-p^TQ^+p)\ge 0 
$$

Comment: I can't figure out what Q^+ implies. Please tell me!

Comment: $Q^+$ is pseudo-inverse matrix of $Q$, generalization of inverse when $Q$ is singular. One of it's properties is $Q^+QQ^+=Q^+$ and if $Qy=p$ and $Qs=0$ iff $p^Ts=0$ then $QQ^+p=p$ and $y=Q^+p$.

Comment: How do you find $Q$ is positive semi-definite?

Comment: In the symmetric case, it means that the minimum eigenvalue is zero or greater.

Comment: This may be trivial, but I think $r > 0$ is false and $r\geq0$ is true.

Comment: Could you please explain why $r \geq p^TQ^+p$?

Comment: Yes it is typo. $r\ge 0$.

Comment: Ok let me explain. $F(x)\ge 0$ for all $x$ implies semi definitness of $Q$. Thus $F(x)$ can be rewritten as I did. But then for $x=-Q^+p$ : $F(-Q^+p)=r-p^TQ^+QQ^+p\ge 0$

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner Thank you! May I also ask how $F(x) \geq 0$ implies positive semi-definitness of $Q$, i.e., $x^TQx \geq 0 \; \forall x $?

Comment: If $Q$ has a negative eigenvalue take $x=-kv$ where $v$ is normalized corresponding eigenvector and $k>0$ is large enough. Then $F(-kv)$ will be negative.

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner May I ask you why $Qx = 0$ implies $p^T x = 0?$

Comment: Because if $p^Tx\ne 0$ taking large enough with $p^Tx<0$ you will make $F(x)<0$.

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner Thank you again for your time! Your argument only considers $x$'s with $p^Tx < 0$. What about the other possible $x$ values, e.g., is it not possible that for some $x$ such that $p^Tx > 0$ it holds $x^TQx < 0$ even though $F(x) \geq 0$?

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner Thank you for your answering! You mean: if $p^Tx > 0$, you can take negatively large $k \in R$, and replace $x$ with $\xi=kx$, and get $F(x) < 0$ ($Q\xi=0$), and if $p^Tx < 0$, then positively large $k$, and these results contradicts $F(x) \geq 0$. Is my comprehension right?

Comment: Yes, you got it.

Comment: @Stelios, I answered  already it  cannot be $xTQx<0$  because it makes $F(x)<0$ for $x$ large enough. This is why $Q$ is positively at least semi definite.

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner I still don't see how this "large" $x$ statement is valid for small $x$, but I guess I will have to work on it! :) thanks a lot!